# In R what is the difference between lda() and linDA() functions?

Tags: r

So I am trying to understand the difference between lda and linDA from DiscriMiner package. Both claim to perform linear discriminant analysis.
My goal is to retrieve from lda some analogue of $functions object which linDA has.

The problem is linDA doesn't perform when there are collinear variables in one categories while lda performs with warning.

```
library(DiscriMiner)
library(MASS)
stack_df = data.frame(a = c(4.4, 5.4, 4.1, 4.3, 4.6, 9.2, 9.7, 10, 11, 16, 16, 17),
                      b = c(100, 111, 99, 104, 107, 55, 61, 54, 60, 333, 341, 299))
clusters <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
result_lda <- lda(x = stack_df, grouping = clusters)
result_linDA <- linDA(variables = stack_df, group = clusters)
result_linDA$functions
```

How do i get output like this from lda:

```
                  1            2           3
constant -89.811195 -170.4324589 -975.199938
a         15.892524   29.3741508   55.378398
b          1.011531    0.7940963    3.216177
```

Here is how result_lda looks like:

```
Call:
lda(stack_df, grouping = clusters)

Prior probabilities of groups:
        1         2         3 
0.4166667 0.3333333 0.2500000 

Group means:
         a        b
1  4.56000 104.2000
2  9.97500  57.5000
3 16.33333 324.3333

Coefficients of linear discriminants:
         LD1         LD2
a 1.16933652 -1.18114662
b 0.07679703  0.04925105

Proportion of trace:
   LD1    LD2 
0.9207 0.0793
```

Comment: Please include all the packages used.

Comment: I get `Error in lda(x = stack_df, grouping = clusters) : 
  could not find function "lda"` after loading the package

Comment: I believe DiscriMiner was enough to reproduce as lda is a core function. Am I wrong?

Comment: I find `MASS` having `lda`

Comment: Could you please try loading MASS package?

Comment: yes, i loaded, from the structure, it doens't look like lda calculates it